# jdk8 struts 1.1 jasper-report 1.2

Tags: java, jasper-reports, struts-1

I work on a project where all the java infrastructure has been set up around 2005 and has never been upgraded since.
We plan to upgrade to the latest java version (jdk 8u60) and we are trying to minimize the code rework and the external dependencies upgrade.

We are trying to collect information about really old (EOL ) java library compatibility with the latest jdk:

- struts 1.1
- jasper-report 1.2

Do someone have a success story in using struts 1.1 with jdk8 ? jasper 1.2 ?

A list of common compatibility/incompatibility issues ?

Regards,

Comment: Hade troubles with old jasper report on java 8 had to upgrade to 6.0 or above. (see some on internet you will find alot of issues)